# Android play-services not working when imported as AAR file

Tags: android-studio, unity-game-engine, gradle, google-play-services, android-gps

I am trying to write a simple GPS plugin in android studio
To do this i have dependencies on `play-services-maps` and `play-services-location`
At first the module compiles as expected
But since i need to use this plugin in Unity, i must somehow include these gradle dependencies in my plugin.(i couldn't get Unity to import these dependencies by itself no matter what i did)
So i have downloaded these repositories from maven as a .aar file and added to the libs folder.   And replaced these lines:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
```

with these:

```
implementation files('libs/play-services-maps-17.0.0.aar')  
implementation files('libs/play-services-location-17.0.0.aar')
```

Now when i try to Make my module i get the error:

```
locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
                                 ^
  class file for com.google.android.gms.common.internal.ReflectedParcelable not found
```

**this is my manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.gpsmodule">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
</manifest>
```

**this is my class:**

```
package com.example.gpsmodule;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationResult;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

public class GPSWrapper {
    private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;
    private LocationRequest locationRequest;
    private LocationCallback locationCallback;
    private Activity activity;

    public GPSWrapper(Activity ac) {
        activity = ac;
        getGPS();
    }

    public void getGPS() {

        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(activity);

        locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setInterval(0);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(0);
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

        locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
                Location location = locationResult.getLastLocation();
                Log.d("GPSWrapper", "fresh location received");
            }
        };

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }

        fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, null);
    }
}
```

**this is my gradle:**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles "consumer-rules.pro"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    //implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0' // this actually work
    //implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'//this actually work
    implementation files('libs/play-services-maps-17.0.0.aar') // this line break the Make
    implementation files('libs/play-services-location-17.0.0.aar')// this line break the Make
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'


    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

Any idea what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

So the answer came from an unexpected direction,
Apparently i don't need to include the libraries my plugin depend on inside the plugin JAR file,
Instead of packing the libraries in the plugin itself - i can simply edit the `gradleTemplate.properties` file in UNITY.
So that UNITY will download and pack them in compile time.
To do that go to File ->Build Settings -> Player Settings-> Publishing Settings
Check the "**Custom Main Gradle Template**" to enable editing of the gradle file in UNITY.
Then, inside the UNITY editor project tab go to Assets->Plugins->Android
Right click on the `gradleTemplate.properties` and select `show in explorer`
Now you can open the file with any text editor and than add your dependencies just as you did in Android Studio